# Upper bound for an iterated integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The integral taken over R, the area bounded by curves y = 0, x = 1, and y = x. The function we are integrating is f(x,y) = $sin(x^{1000}y)$.

So the integral is $\int_0^1 \int_0^x sin(x^{1000}y)dydx$

$= \int_0^1 \frac{1-cos(x^{1001})}{x^{1000}}$

But I have been having trouble getting any further than that. I know that the integrand here is less than or equal to 1-cos(1) but that does not help in proving either of the inequalities I have been asked to prove.

Which reminds me, I am asked to prove that the integral is less than or equal to both $\frac{sin(1)}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2004}$.

I would greatly appreciate any help or hints, even if it is just in proving one of the two inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with simple estimates  instead of evaluating complex explicit integral. We have that
$$
0\le \sin(x^{1000}y)\le \sin(1),\quad \sin(x^{1000}y)\le x^{1000}y\tag{*}
$$ by monotonicity of $t\mapsto \sin t$ on $[0,1]$ and the fact that $\sin t\le t$ for all $t\ge 0$. From $(*)$, it follows that
$$
0\le I\le \int_0^1\int_0^x  \sin(1)\mathrm dy\mathrm dx =\frac{\sin(1)}{2}
$$ and
$$
0\le I\le \int_0^1\int_0^x x^{1000}y \ \mathrm dy\mathrm dx =\frac1{2006}.
$$ This gives the estimate as wanted.